# Formatting Date Time in BIRT Reports

Tags: date, format, report, birt

I have an issue working with date time in BIRT Reports.  All I want to do is given a date time, from either a Report Parameter, Date Time column in a data set, or even using new Date() in some java script, I want to format the value using local time.

So given the date as 2011-06-25 23:00:00 (which is always stored in universal time), I want to format it as 2011-06-26 00:00:00 BST (as I am running in UTC Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London timezone.

Using the built in Format DateTime settings the closest I have come is formatting 2011-06-25 23:00:00 in the Report as 2011-06-25 23:00:00 GMT.

I have posted this on the [BIRT Exhchange forum](http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/22979-formatting-date-time-in-local-time/) also so hopefully someone can help.

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Andez

Comment: Did you find a solution?  The BIRT Exchange Forum looks like it ended without a solution in August 2011.  There is a reference to  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353324 but it looks like it is still open.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found so far is setting the timezone by the parameter "__timezone":

For example:

```
..&__timezone=CET
..&__timezone=BST
```